# Simplify $\arccos\left(2\cos x\right)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Let $x\in[\pi/3,2\pi/3]$. We know that $\arccos (\cos x)=x$ but what we can say about $\arccos\left(2\cos x\right)$?

Are there, for example, any "half-angle formula" also for inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: My instincts tell me that there's trouble ahead. For example, what happens if $\cos x>1/2$?

Comment: The domain issues aside, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos(2+cos+x)) doesn't give a nice simplification. That more or less implies none exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others already, there is no nice simplification of $\cos^{-1}(2\cos(x))$, but the following similar-looking identities hold:

> $\cos(2\cos^{-1}(x)) = 2x^2-1$ for any $x \in [-1,1]$.
>
> $\cos(\frac12\cos^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{\frac12(x+1)}$ for any $x \in [-1,1]$.

Both can be easily proven by the double-angle formula.

Answer (score -1):

$\arccos(2\cos x)$ can not be defined for $x∈(0,π)$ it can only be defined for $x∈[π/3,2π/3]$. So I don't think it is useful to make calculation for a function with such a domain (Neither useful nor practical)

Comment: The function $\arccos(2\cos x)$ can be defined at $x = \pi/3$ and at $x = 2\pi/3$.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my post.